# GPIO pin not providing as much current as 3.3V pin

Tags: gpio, output, current

I have an infrared led which works at 3.3V.
This is the led [image].

Edit: I couldn't find any specific documentation, it's one of those led you usually attach to rpi infrared cameras.

If I attach it directly to the 3.3V pin it draws about 4mA, while when attached to a GPIO pin set as output (still providing 3.3V) it is only able to draw about 0.3mA emitting much less light.

Why is that?

Comment: @Seamus it's just chinese stuff I bought off of Amazon, it has no documentation at all. It's one of those ir led you usually attach to rpi ir cameras.

Comment: @joan even if that was the case, it still does not explain the fact that the led is much brighter while on the 3.3V pin than on a gpio.

Comment: @joan oh got it. Then I'll have to check with another tester.

Comment: @Seamus man it's 5 bucks stuff for free time entertainment, I don't have to build a nuclear reactor... I had what I considered a strange behaviour described in the question so I asked, if I can't figure it out it's not that big of a deal. Of course I set the pin to HIGH... As I said in the question the led lights up, it's just dimmer, like it can't draw enough current, I'll take the measurements again with another tester to be sure.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the code and a drawing,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Seamus and how exactly did you infer that I don't care? I just said it's not a mission critical issue... If I didn't care I wouldn't have bothered asking

Comment: @Seamus yeah sure. Now please do yourself a HUGE favor, let it go.

Answer (score 0):

Your figures don't seem to be correct.

Depending on Pi model you might be able to draw up to 500 mA from the 3V3 rail.

You can only safely draw about 16 mA of current from a single GPIO.

Comment: I don't know, I'm trusting my tester here. I just switch from the 3.3V pin to a gpio and it drops from 4mA to 0.3mA. Also the emitted light becomes much dimmer so the measures look on point to me.

Comment: well, I'm just closing the pin-led-gnd circuit through an ammeter...